# $\gcd (m,n)\cdot \gcd (n,k)\cdot \gcd(m,k)\cdot \text{lcm} (m,n,k)^2=lcm (m,n)*lcm (n,k)*lcm (m,k)*\gcd (m,n,k)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$m, n, k$ are three positive integers.

I am lost in the problem and cant find a way out. Please solve it as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The highest power of prime $p$ that divides $m,n,k$ be $M,N,K$

WLOG $M\ge N\ge K$

The highest exponent of $p$ LHS will be $N+K+K+2M$

For RHS the exponent is $=M+N+M+2K$

This holds true for any prime

Comment: Problem is about product and not sum

Comment: @,user659479, Please find the rectified version

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the solution